# React Native running in emulator gives bundling failed: permission denied error

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, react-native, manjaro

I have just created a project with `react-native init` on Manjaro Linux and opened it with Android Studio .  I then ran `react-native start` on a terminal and then ran the app on an existing emulator which opened to a red screen stating:

```
The development server returned response error code: 500
Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details
```

On my terminal window, it gave me the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/metro-cache/52/45f310fea946062ca0c3c6122dec6592f224f34ee755285a39fd0922f1d4c6739388c3'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1163:35)
    at FileStore.set (/home/user/ReactNativeProjects/albums/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/FileStore.js:43:8)
    at Cache.set (/home/user/ReactNativeProjects/albums/node_modules/metro-cache/src/Cache.js:96:31)
    at /home/user/ReactNativeProjects/albums/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:287:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/user/ReactNativeProjects/albums/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:11:657)
    at /home/us/ReactNativeProjects/albums/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:11:817
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

I checked the `/tmp/metro-cache/52` folder but did not find the mentioned file.  Does anybody know what may be causing this error?  Note that when I run it on my physical device with `$ react-native run-android`, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you solved it? Help me, I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/metro-cache
cd /tmp/metro-cache
sudo chown -R $USER .
```

Actually, I am not sure which one is worked. Probably chown is enough.

Comment: This works like a charm. I was stuck here for 2 hours. thanks, you are the lifesaver.

Comment: Works like charm hey