# Android Bundling failed EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/metro-cache/3b/

Tags: android, reactjs, permissions

Anyone familiar with this issue?

[VS Code and emulator shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7nyH.png)

[metro bundler shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE8FE.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to this question: [React Native running in emulator gives bundling failed: permission denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622425/react-native-running-in-emulator-gives-bundling-failed-permission-denied-error)

Try the solution under it, it solves my problem.

As suggested by @sloppypasta , here is commands to use:

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp/metro-cache
cd /tmp/metro-cache
sudo chown -R $USER .
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant portions of the linked source here, to both improve searchability and protect against changes to the linked content.